# Scrolling content in a kindle book

Tags: kindle

I'm wondering if anyone is aware of a way to scroll content in a kindle book. I thought I had the problem solved by using [calibre](http://calibre-ebook.com/) but I quickly discovered that since the content is DRMed, I'm not allowed to read the book with this reader. *lame*

The specific book I'm reading has code examples in it, but it is difficult to follow them without being able to specifically scroll through the examples. This doesn't even touch on the fact that the code content is also poorly formatted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't scroll (I'm assuming you mean like you do on your computer) but you can do `Menu > Go To` and enter a location so if the code sample is half on one page and half on the other, you can get it all on one page.

Alternatively, you can read the book on the Kinle app for your computer in which you should be able to display more on the screen.

Comment: so i just have to guess and check the location for the starting point of the code block?

Comment: Not really, you can see the current location at the bottom of your screen. I've found on my Kindle Keyboard that incrementing the location by 1 scrolls 3 or 4 lines. You can use that to position your code block at (as close to) the top of the page.